# MySQL Date For Monthly Reporting

Tags: mysql, date

I need some help with running a query at month end. Each 1st working day of a month may differ, and therefore I may only be at work on the 3rd of a given month.

I am trying to figure out what my WHERE statement would look like to select data for the current month, unless it is:
1st of a month, then it will need to select everything from the previous month
1st working day of a month, which could be the 3rd. It will then also need to select the previous month's data.

These are two scenarios I am currently playing with, and don't have data to test it with as yet.

I have thought about doing

```
WHERE
MONTH(action_date) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

But this then also returns data from 2016.

I have also thought of doing

```
WHERE 
action_date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

But this would not work if today was say Monday the 3rd.

I would appreciate any answers that would give me the best way of doing this

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I would have a calender/dates table which would have a flag indicating the first working date in the month and drive such reports off that. if you are not allowed to do this (and it could be in a separate schema) you could also join to a sub query on containing all the first working days for some years to come).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply subtract a few more days or even a month from the date, as all you will actually get from the subtraction is a month anyway

```
MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY))
```

OR

```
MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: The problem with subtracting say 3 days means that if today is Wednesday the 3rd. I will get data from last month, but if today is Wednesday the 3rd I want data for this month.

So I need to check both the day name and date.